# Is there a way to tell how much memory is file-backed on Linux process?

Tags: linux, memory, proc, mmap

I'm looking to see how much of my memory is file-backed on a process.  Unfortunately proc/pid/smap_rollup shows stats for how much memory is being used, but it doesn't seem to differentiate between file-backed and non-file-backed memory.   Is there an easy way to tell this? (ideally I only care about shared file-backed memory)